# Azure - Configuring authentication to a blob storage in an Azure Storage Account from an Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-application-gateway, azure-storage-account

I have configured an Application Gateway with an Azure Storage Account blob as a backend target in a Backend Pool.

This enables public access to the contents of the blob storage via the App Gateway. However, when **Blob anonymous access** is **disabled** the health probe is receiving a 409 error (PublicAccessNotPermitted).

To resolve this issue I've assigned **Storage Blob Data Reader** permissions to the Managed Identity of the Application Gateway.

Unfortunately this hasn't resolved the issue. Is there a way for the Application Gateway to successfully authenticate with the Storage Account?

If not it seems the only other option would be to create a Static Website on the Storage Account.

Comment: Hi @user2794745, How do you added Managed Identity to the Application Gateway?

Comment: I can't remember if it was created when the the Application Gateway was created, or if I created it using the Azure CLI at a later date. The identity can be found using the CLI:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/application-gateway/identity?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-application-gateway-identity-show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure - Configuring authentication to a blob storage in an Azure Storage Account from an Application Gateway.

`Azure Application Gateway` does not support managed identities for accessing `Azure Storage Accounts` with authentication; it only supports managed identities for `Azure Key Vault.`

To access an `Azure Storage Account` from an `Application Gateway'`s public IP, ensure that your storage is accessible over the public network. It is not possible to access the storage account authorized by using Managed Identity from the Application Gateway.

Once I enable public access to the `storage account`, I will be able to access it from the `application gateway`.

[image]

Reference: [Manage application identities securely and automatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/benchmark/azure/baselines/application-gateway-security-baseline#im-3-manage-application-identities-securely-and-automatically)